# S4 object deep copy

Tags: r, clone, r-s4

I am attaching code below for more clarity; I have a matrix of S4 objects called grid, each object has a state and a hashmap as shown in the class definition.

```
cell <- setClass(
  # Set the name for the class
  "cell",

  # Define the slots
  slots = c(
    state = "numeric",
    code = "hash"
  ),

  # Set the default values for the slots.
  prototype=list(
    state = 1
  )
)

setGeneric(name="copy_cell",
           def= function(x, y){
             standardGeneric("copy_cell")
           })

setMethod(f = "copy_cell", signature = "cell",
          definition = function(x, y) {
            x@state = y@state
            x@code = copy(y@code)

          })

grid <- matrix( sapply(1:(20*20), function(x){
  new("cell",
      state = ifelse(runif(1)<= 0.5, 3, 1),
      code = hash())
}), 20, 20)
```

I want to copy the contents of this grid into nextgrid. Because the object contains a hashmap (which is an environment, which is passed by reference), a simple: `nextgrid = grid` wont do it. I made a function that works for individually created cells:

```
cell1 = new("cell", state = ifelse(runif(1)<= 0.5, 3, 1), code = hash("a",1))
cell2 = new("cell")
cell2 = copy_cell(cell2, cell1)
```

But I am having a hard time implementing a way to apply the function over all the cells of the matrix. Below, I first copy grid into nextgrid to avoid re-initializing another whole matrix of objects, and then use an sapply.

```
nextgrid = grid
sapply(grid[,], function(x) copy_cell(nextgrid[,], x))
```

I get the error: Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable): unable to find an inherited method for function ‘copy_cell’ for signature ‘"matrix"’.
Which I understand because I seem to be passing a matrix to the function rather than individual cells...but I am not sure how to re-write it correctly...

I tried rewriting my class using R6 objects that have a nice clone/deep clone method, but I was having a really hard time slicing my matrix for other operations, so I am a little stuck.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use copy constructors from the R5 reference classes. Note that a "hash" attribute is really special in a reference classes, as the function name `copy` for hash maps coincides with the name of the copy constructor. We can use `eval.parent(quote(copy))` as a workaround to retrieve the copy constructor.

Further note that copying an empty hash map (i.e., `copy(hash())`) fails. Seems to be a bug (or a feature?) of the hash library. Because of this I also added one object to the hash-map of the grid entries.

```
library(hash)

cell <- setRefClass(
  # Set the name for the class
  "cell",

  # Define the slots
  fields = list(
    state = "numeric",
    code = "hash"
  ),

  methods = list(
    # Default constructor
    initialize = function(state, code) {
      .self$state = state
      .self$code = code
    },

    # Copy constructor
    copy = function(shallow = FALSE) {
      # Get the copy-function for hash from the parent environment
      cp <- eval.parent(quote(copy))
      # do the copy
      cell(.self$state, cp(code))
    }
  )
)


# Create cell and copy it
cell1 = cell(ifelse(runif(1)<= 0.5, 3, 1), hash("a",1))
cell2 = cell1$copy()

# Let's convince ourselves that we did a deep copy
cell1$code[["a"]]=5
cell2


# Create grid and copy it
grid <- matrix( sapply(1:(20*20), function(x){
  cell(ifelse(runif(1)<= 0.5, 3, 1), hash("a",1))
}), 20, 20)
nextgrid = apply(grid, c(1,2), function(x) x[[1]]$copy())

# Let's again convince ourselves that we did a deep copy
grid[[1,1]]$code["a"] = 5
nextgrid[[1,1]]
```

Comment: right. How would you create a grid with the current set up? and say that I wanted to ensure that all the cells in the first and last row, and the first and last column had state = 1, is there an efficient way to do that?

Comment: Just scroll down the to see how the grid is created :) You could use `grid[20,]<-lapply(1:20,function(x) cell(x,hash()))` for assigning values to the last row.